# 'Mediainfo' permission denied AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, node-modules, mediainfo

I have a lambda function for making thumbnails from videos, but I'm encountering some issues when I try to use the mediainfo module. I get the same problem when I test the function

> /var/task/node_modules/mediainfo-wrapper/lib/linux64/mediainfo: Permission denied.

I changed the permission of the whole folder before zipping it (first to 644, then to 755 and 777) but nothing changes. Could I get some king of advice on what can be causing the issue?

Comment: I was able to fix it changing  just the file permission